# Work around for || operator when checking strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a really simple culture srting check like so

```
if(culture.ToUpper() == "ES-ES" || "IT-IT")
{
   //do something
}
else
{
  //do some other thing
}
```

since you can't use the || in this case what would be another short approach around this other than an else if statement?

Comment: Save the result of `culture.ToUpper()` in a variable and or each comparison, or make a method that takes a `params string[]`

Comment: Did you intend to do `if(culture.ToUpper() == "ES-ES" || culture.ToUpper() == "IT-IT")` instead?

Comment: Yes, I completely missed that and was wondering why I kept getting an error. Needed the another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to define an extension method that abstracts away the comparison here and have it take all of the values via a `params` array

```
static bool EqualsAny(this string str, params string[] args) { 
  foreach (var arg in args) { 
    if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(arg, str)) { 
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
if (culture.EqualsAny("ES-ES", "IT-IT")) { 
  ...
} else { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: This could be very useful as I will be doing quite of a few of these checks as the number of different country localizations grows, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That isn't valid syntax.  Rewrite it like this:

```
if(culture.ToUpper() == "ES-ES" || culture.ToUpper() == "IT-IT")
```

Comment: [See this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) `i => İ`, `ı => I`. So it should be `.ToUpperInvariant()`

Comment: @L.B You are correct.  The OP was using ToUpper so I used it as well.  He may have a valid reason for doing it that way and I didn't want to assume anything.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest one:

```
if(culture.ToUpper() == "ES-ES" || culture.ToUpper() == "IT-IT")
{
   //do something
}
else
{
  //do some other thing
}
```

one I'd use:

```
if((new [] { "ES-ES", "IT-IT" }).Contains(culture.ToUpper()))
{
   //do something
}
else
{
  //do some other thing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being thorough and providing both options. Will mark this as the answer because of that for when others run into the same problem.

Comment: Great answer, Marcin.  +1

Comment: Question though, what would be the over all benefit of the second approach?

Comment: With this approach `string.ToUpper` is only called once. To achieve the same with `||` you'd have to declare a variable before `if` statement. Some people may say it's not very readable, but I don't think it's hard to understand at all. And also because of how `Contains` method is implemented, it will act like `||` does - it will return `true` as soon as first matching element is found without iterating over entire collection.

Comment: [See this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) `i => İ`, `ı => I`. So it should be `.ToUpperInvariant`

Comment: @L.B I know about that, but I don't think that the question is about that. You should probably put that comment in the question itself as well.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think you should have provided a complete/correct  answer as JaredPar did